# AWS Quicksight content gone (databases, analysis, dashboards)

Tags: amazon-iam, amazon-quicksight

i just logged into my Quicksight account and all my stuff is gone (no databases, no analysis, no dashboards, no recent viewed stuff). Also my colleague can´t see anything. We are in the correct account and correct location. Also we are both admins and nobody touched the Quicksight account.

Do we need to enable something in the account management or something?

Comment: Same happened to me today. Did you ever get a solution for this?